# SSRS Parameter That Queries ALL When NULL and Can Query on MULTIPLE Values Without Options Listed

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a business requirement that requires a user to be able to search for many different order numbers and be presented with additional information through my report. Since we have a very large amount of orders on any given day, I want them to be able to copy and paste the list into the SSRS Parameter (which I have setup fine now). I also want them to be able to run the report 'wide open' and have them be able to leave the parameter blank and return all orders.

I have achieved this in the past while using 'Available Values' for the parameter. But, now that I am doing it manually, I am coming across a lot of pesky errors.

I believe I am close.. I have the following simplified query:

```
SELECT 
AssignmentNumber, 
OrderNumber 
FROM 
tables.Activity
WHERE 
((OrderNumber in (@P_ORDER_NUMBER)) or (@P_ORDER_NUMBER = ''))
```

When I run this, I have success in 2 of 3 scenerios

1. When @P_ORDER_NUMBER is left empty, it returns all orders
2. When a SINGLE order is provided, it returns assignments on that order

The final issue is getting it to work with multiple Orders. I am getting an Error in SSRS reading 'An Expression of Non-Boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.

I assume there's in issue in the OR clause that I have.. but I haven't been able to find a workaround that meets the business need. Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: What does the value inside `@P_ORDER_NUMBER` look like?

Comment: *"return all orders"* for all time? I'm not sure that's wise..

Comment: You won't be able to do this with a direct query with SSRS. You'll need to use a stored procedure and a string splitter.

Answer (score 0):

The following is not perfect, as it won't work if some orders are selected and then the report is re-run with no orders selected but is might be OK for your needs...

Add a new parameter to the report, I called it `pBlank` in my tests. You can set this to hidden once the report is complete. In the default value I used the following expression.

```
=IIF(LEN(Parameters!P_ORDER_NUMBER.Value(0)) = 0, 1, 0)
```

So it will be 1 if the order parameter is empty or 0 of it is not empty. It does this by checking the length of the first value. This is assuming the user does not have add a blank value as the first value, if they do then you could do something similar by checking the .Count property too.

Then just change the dataset query to something like

```
SELECT 
        AssignmentNumber, 
        OrderNumber 
    FROM tables.Activity
    WHERE (
           OrderNumber in (@P_ORDER_NUMBER) 
           OR @pBlank = 1
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

It may just be hung up on the empty string concept. Try allowing the parameter to be NULL - the user will get a little checkbox that says "null" - and for the parameter prompt say

`Enter order number(s) or check "null" for all:`

Change your query to `...or (@P_ORDER_NUMBER IS NULL)`

This has always worked for me. HTH